# Start NiFi Docker with custom .nar and workflow

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I am trying to get the `apache/nifi` `v1.6.0` image to work in docker with a custom `.nar` and `workflow`.

What is the correct way to copy these resources into the container and ensure that NiFi restarts to respect them?

At at the moment I have a dockerfile looking like this:

```
FROM apache/nifi:latest

COPY my_nar.nar nifi-1.6.0/lib/

COPY my_workflow.xml /opt/nifi/conf/

EXPOSE 8080
```

This seems to run, but I'm not seeing the `.nar` or `workflow` in the nifi instance when it starts.

Where do I need to put these and how do I tell the Nifi container to use them?

EDIT:
**This is my final working dockerfile**

```
FROM apache/nifi:latest

COPY my_nar.nar /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/lib/

COPY my_template.xml /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/conf/templates

COPY --chown=nifi:nifi flow.xml.gz /opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/conf/

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: As the COPY target locations specify nifi-1.6.0, for robustness you may want to explicitly specify that NiFi version for the image, e.g.: 
FROM apache/nifi:1.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying your XML file will not work as you anticipate.  NiFi's main flow is driven by a flow.xml.gz.  You could copy that from a currently running instance into the folder in place of your my_workflow.xml template.

Alternatively, once the instance is running, you could choose to import the template (my_workfow.xml) and then instantiate an instance of it onto your canvas.

Regardless of either approach laid out above, you should see your expected flow and, if they are being utilized, the associated extensions in the bundled NAR.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've now managed to get the .nar copied in and working if I manually import the template. I tried copying the `flow.xml.gz` as suggested but unfortunately that gives me the following exception `org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.`

Comment: I should have looked deeper, the error was due to the COPY to the container copying as root and the nifi:nifi user not having access to run it. chown fixed that

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working.  If you find any shortcomings or functionality you would like, please feel free to file a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI.

Comment: I think the only problem was tracking down what to do. I'm writing a blog post to help others

Comment: Great!  If you want some eyes and to help some other folks out, I would recommend sharing it to the NiFI mailing lists.  I'm sure it would be a great resource! https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html

Comment: I did write an article in the end, will post to the list but it's here if anyone is interested: http://dougmcdonald.co.uk/running-nifi-in-docker/